# How do I partially-expose object contents in an object library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, visibility, unix-ar, multiple-definition-error

I'm compiling some C++ code into a library. Suppose my source files are `mylib.cpp` and `util.cpp`. The code in `util.cpp` is used in the library implementation, but is not part of the library in the sense that code using the library cannot call it (it's not in the public headers) and should not be aware of its existence; but `my_lib.cpp` includes `util.hpp` and does rely on the compiled `util.cpp` object code.

Now, if I compile `mylib.o` and `util.o`, then perform:

```
ar qc libmylib.a mylib.o util.o
```

my library works just fine; but - the utility code is exposed as symbols. Thus, if I link this library with some other code, there might be clashes of double-definitions. Or that other code might inappropriately rely on symbols being available (e.g. with its own header).

How can I ensure that only the object code in `mylib.o` (and in `util.o`) "sees" the symbols from `util.o`, while outside code does not?

Note: I believe this question stands also for C and perhaps other compiled languages.

Comment: If privacy is a major concern, I'd probably consider including `util.cpp` (as well as `util.hpp`) into the source for `mylib.cpp` (`#include "util.cpp"`) with appropriate namespace controls so that the code is available inside `mylib.cpp` but not outside (anonymous namespace, or `namespace mylib::Private` or some such scheme). This is not particularly conventional, but it is probably effective (once you've worked out the necessary tweaks). The chances are that the combination TU (translation unit) is not so big as to cause your compiler major problems. This doesn't rely on compiler extensions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Including the .cpp is an interesting suggestion. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

If your C++ library has its own namespace, then using that or a sub-namespace is nominally the correct way to control access to the internal utilities.  It sounds as if your code is not providing template classes — the constraints for those have to be thought through separately.

If privacy is a major concern, I'd probably consider including `util.cpp` (as well as `util.hpp`) into the source for `mylib.cpp` (meaning `#include "util.cpp"`) with appropriate namespace controls so that the code from `util.cpp` is available inside `mylib.cpp` but not outside (using an anonymous namespace, or `namespace mylib::Private` or some such scheme). This is not very conventional, but it is probably effective (once you've worked out the necessary tweaks). The chances are that the combination TU (translation unit) is not so big as to cause your compiler major problems. This doesn't rely on compiler extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fallback "solution", which is actually a workaround:

I keep the public visibility, but I burden all of the code in `util.cpp` with some element of naming which will make it effectively unique. For example, I may enclose those functions with a `namespace mylib`. Not the (demangled) symbols are all `mylib::foo()` (or `mylib::util::foo()`). They will be searched, but it is reasonable to assume they won't match anything outside of the mylib code.

In addition to the hassle, this has the detriment of still allowing external code to depend on this internal utility code - if it does so intentionally.

Comment: I don't think that you can truly hide some code from a static library in the general case. Unnamed namespaces have such an effect but limited to a single source file. You could obfuscate some names but that would be a hassle and objects would be still accessible anyway. Your solution based on nested namespaces is clean and commonly used for this purpose. But if confidentiality matters, then I think that you should release a dynamic (shared) library instead of a static one, so that you can explicitly choose what is exported.

Comment: @luciole75w: It's not about confidentiality. That is, I don't mind that a forensic examination of the library finds everything. Can you develop your suggestion regarding a dynamic library into an answer?

Comment: By confidentiality I was more thinking about access restriction to prevent an external application from linking with your private utils. Well the way to create/use a dynamic (linked) library and expose symbols depends on your compilation tools. With MSVC you can declare variables/functions/types with `__declspec(dllexport)` to expose them (or list them in a separate file) then the linker will generate an import library to easily link your binaries with. Wih GCC you would use `__attribute__((visibility("...")))` but I have not done that for a long time.